# Maven flag for testing connection to repo?

Tags: maven, mule, pom.xml, anypoint-studio

Using Anypoint studio for our Mulesoft API development, I have recently noticed an issue that I would like to try and solve. We use Maven/pom files to include dependencies that are needed for the project and it populates the local `.m2` repository when running/build the app locally.

Some of our custom dependencies live in our artifactory that is behind a firewall (when out of the office). If I am not on the VPN, it will not connect to the artifactory, thus can't get the dependencies.

The problem with this is when I don't realize that I'm not on the network, it will try to connect to the repo and it ends up hitting a Cloudflare login page. Maven for some reason saves this HTML as the contents of the dependencies pom.xml, corrupting it.

When the API then tries to run, the dependencies are invalid so that prompts me to then connect, rebuild the repo etc.

**Question:**

Is there a flag or way to check that the repo was able to connect and has a valid POM file, and if it doesn't, alert/fail to build? I assume that if the connection failed completely and threw a 400 error of some sort, this might happen. However, because its prompting with the login page, it receives it as a 200 and proceeds.

Any way to solve for this outside of me just not forgetting to connect to VPN?

Comment: I recommend to turn on checksum policy etc. see https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the post @khmarbaise linked to, you can also use the -C option to force checksum verification from the command line, which is an alias for --strict-checksums. It appears that not all servers provide checksums so you will have to test it.

I have seen this error happen in the past. Why Maven allows 'corrupt' pom files to be stored in the first place is beyond me.